# There was an error sending mail from bugzilla server

Tags: smtp, bugzilla

```
 URL: http://<mydomain>/index.cgi?GoAheadAndLogIn=Log%20in
There was an error sending mail from '@<mydomain>' to '<my-email>@outlook.com': no sender

Traceback:

 at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 179.
    Bugzilla::Mailer::MessageToMTA(...) called at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 221
    Bugzilla::Mailer::send_staged_mail(...) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 1248
    Bugzilla::DB::bz_commit_transaction(...) called at Bugzilla/Auth/Persist/Cookie.pm line 57
    Bugzilla::Auth::Persist::Cookie::persist_login(...) called at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 157
    Bugzilla::Auth::_handle_login_result(...) called at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 82
    Bugzilla::Auth::login(...) called at Bugzilla.pm line 328
    Bugzilla::login(...) called at /var/www/html/bugzilla/index.cgi line 21
```

Hey everyone, I'm getting this error when I try to login at my bugzilla service, This began to occur when I tried to generate a new API key to use in others applications. Then, I'm not been able to login at the service. At server side, I tried to change the values of data/params.json at fields "mailfrom", "maintainer", "smtp_username", "smtp_password", "smtp_ssl", "smtp_server and "mail_delivery_method"

One more thing that I'm not understanding it is the change of the "sender" (at the error description) mail to @ instead the value on field "mailfrom".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had the same issue. Change the delivery method to test  `"mail_delivery_method" : "Test",` in params.json. This will disable the email sending, you now can log into the admin console and remove the API Key. Once this is done, you can change the email settings back.